# Associative Array 2nd Heighest Value with the key

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array like this

```
$cal = array("D"=>"35", "I"=>"23", "S"=>"34", "C"=>"2");
```

Now i want to get the 2nd highest value key
For above example By value 2nd height is 34 , So i should get an output "S" as S is the key assigned to 34.

I already tried this

```
$cal = array("D"=>"35", "I"=>"23", "S"=>"34", "C"=>"2");
arsort($cal);
$keys = array_keys($cal);
echo $cal[$keys[1]];
```

But I am getting only 34 in return . But i want they Key 34 is assigned to means "s".

Please note all the values in that array are dynamic .

Thanks

Comment: `$keys[1]` contains what you want or I`m missing something?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, after you have sorted it, you could just move the `next` pointer (shifts to second element since it starts in the first). Then use `key`:

```
next($cal);
$second = key($cal);
echo $second;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7OAKUw)

Comment: or just simply `echo $keys[1];` its sorted anyway

Comment: it worked . I never thought that way, Thank You so much